# Chrome cache protocol: avoid too many redirects

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, http, https, tomcat

I have a server running `apache` on `http` (port 80) and `https` (port 8443).

On the same server I have `tomcat` running `https` (port `443`)

I want to disable `https` 8443 port on apache server, using only port 80. But chrome tryes to load **https**://myserver even if I type **http**://myserver

So it load index page of tomcat [`https` (port `443`)]. In that page I have tryed to make a redirect (301, 302, 307 and also Meta Refresh) but it fall in a redirect loop.

I've found that cleaning chrome cache solves the problem, but there are many clients that are using my web servers and it would be a nightmare clean all their browser cache :)

How can I solve my problem? Please give me any suggestion!!!